# Connecting/Authenticating to CRM Online from an Azure WCF service

Tags: wcf, authentication, azure, dynamics-crm-online

I am looking to connect to CRM 2013 Online from a WCF webservice hosted on Azure.  I have this working correctly on my dev box ( with the WCF service hosted in the Azure compute emulator),and can connect and retrieve data from CRM online with no issues.

To authenticate against CRM online I am passing the organisation, username and password as parameters to the web service method (I know it's not a great idea but this is only a test), and creating the CRMOrganisationService using these - again, this works fine locally.

However when I publish this WCF service to Azure I hit some problems.  The service publishes correctly and can be accessed at the cloudapp.net address, however any attempt to call a method which retrieves data results in an exception back from the server about Microsoft.Identity.dll not being found.

In an attempt to resolve this I rdp'd t the cloud service instance and enabled Windows Identity Foundation 3.5 from the ServerManager feature view.

This now results in an exception "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration' threw an exception."

Any thoughts more than welcome....!

Thanks

Matt

Comment: I am on it too, but I cant connect to the CRM throught WCF service. how you did it?

Comment: WIF 3.5 is now deprecated.  Make sure you are using the right library, what version of .Net are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be due to TLS, dynamics crm 9 and towards only accepts TLS 1.2 connections, if your Azure component, guessing for the information in the question could be Cloud Service/WebRole, is possible that you defaul OS is win server 2008, to support .net framewor 3.5, this OS need a patch to support TLS 1.2, you could upgrade the OS is your WebRole (assuming that is cloud service) and upgrade the .net framework a more recent one.

[microsoft dynamics crm link](https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/b/arbelatechnologiesblog/archive/2018/02/25/transport-layer-security-tls-1-2-connectivity-requirements-for-dynamics-365-online-v9)

Hope it helps